# How do I figure out which options a backbone.js method accepts?

Tags: methods, backbone.js

I am looking at the Backbone.js documentation and I notice that many methods accept options that you can provide, but they aren't specified.

For example, if you look at the [remove() method](http://devdocs.io/backbone/index#Collection-remove), you will see this:

> **remove** collection.remove(models, [options])
>   Remove a model (or an array of models) from the collection, and return them. Each model can be a Model instance, an id string or a JS object, any value acceptable as the id argument of collection.get. Fires a "remove" event for each model, and a single "update" event afterwards. The model's index before removal is available to listeners as options.index.

It doesnt't mention what sort of options it accepts. Many methods in the Backbone.js documentation don't specify the options they accept.

How do I figure out which options a backbone.js method accepts?

Comment: You can always open the source code and check what a method handles from second argument options. BTW It is better to raise an issue regarding this on [github](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/) to get in touch with people behind `backbone` rather than asking here..?

Comment: If it's not in the documentation then use the source. I'm not sure what kind of answer you expect here? A comprehensive guide of all options available to all methods or a link to the github repo?

Answer (score 0):

> remove collection.remove(models, [options])
>
> Remove a model (or an array of models) from the collection, and return
> them. Each model can be a Model instance, an id string or a JS object,
> any value acceptable as the id argument of collection.get. Fires a
> "remove" event for each model, and a single "update" event afterwards,
> unless {silent: true} is passed. The model's index before removal is
> available to listeners as options.index.

The latest Backbone documentation lists at least one option, and it's one of the common ones applicable to any Backbone method which fires an event: `silent`.  If set to true this option will cause the method not to trigger the event it normally would.

So why not clarify that `silent` (or whatever options might apply to a method) are the only ones in the documentation?  Why leave it an ambiguous `options`?

`options` is a generic mechanism Backbone provides for taking any sort of auxiliary information, so the `options` could also be used beyond just the documented options in a few ways ...

1. the method might take options which are undocumented because they are only applicable to a limited number of people, or simply because they are new and the Backbone team hasn't bothered to add the documentation for them.  If you want to "figure out" that these options exist you have to either read about them in the GitHub issue that triggered their addition, or read through the Backbone source code yourself.  I strongly recommend the latter option: Backbone's source code is extremely readable, and you can learn a lot from it.
2. you might want to override the native methods, in which case you might want to take your own options through that same `options` object
3. `options` are passed through to the `trigger` call made by `remove` (or any event-triggering method), which means you can use them to pass information through to event handlers as your own custom "options"